# Shipping a Gluon mobile application with Java 14

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile, java-14, jpackage

Following this question [Gluon Mobile project does not work with gradle 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60292492/3520484), I want to know how to ship an application that uses gluon mobile and Java 14.

From what I read, gluon mobile only supports Java 14 if I use GraalVM with the client plugin (https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin or https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin). I read https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX to learn how to package a JavaFX app, but I don't think it's compatible with GraalVM's native image.

So it looks like I'm stuck. I can't use jpackage/link script above because I can't use Java 14, and if I use the client plugin with GraalVM to be able to use Java14, I can't use the jpackage/link script. How do I ship then?

Can I just ship a zip/jar with my whole gluon mobile app and the JDK module deps maybe? Then I won't need platform specific images or packaging.

My target platforms for now are Win and Mac, at least until I figure this thing out. I'm aware that everything here is quite new, so I'm not looking for miracles.

Comment: Gluon Mobile running on Java/JavaFX 11+, but targeting only desktop, does not necessary need GraalVM. You can use the JavaFX gradle/maven plugins, and also fat jar/jlink/jpackage, like any other Java/JavaFX 11+ project. With the Client plugin you can create a native image, and just distribute an executable, but also this is the only way to deploy to mobile.

Comment: @JoséPereda but then I run into the problem that jfxmobile doesn't work with gradle 6 that java 14 needs. I still want a mobile application to run on desktop since we are "simulating" on a desktop what a mobile app would look like, so we need Charm. Does Charm not reply on jfxmobile if it is run on desktop? Do i just comment out the jfxmobile plugin?

Comment: You don't need jfxmobile anymore. Use one of the Client samples (like [HelloGluon](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/tree/master/Maven/HelloGluon)) to get started. It uses Gluon Mobile for Java 11+, JavaFX 11+, you can run it with Java 14 and the JavaFX maven(gradle) plugin, on desktop. No need for GraalVM (yet) if you don't run the client plugin.

Comment: @JoséPereda Oh, so the client plugin can work without GraalVM. That was not clear from the github instructions pages. Thanks, I will try!

Comment: @JoséPereda btw do I need the org.openjfx.javafxplugin along with com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin? or is the former included already?

Comment: I didn't say that. The HelloGluon sample I linked includes the JavaFX plugin and the Client plugin, but you can use only the former and don't use the later. In any case, jfxmobile plugin is no longer required.

Comment: @Mark I still do not understand exactly what your goals are. I think you are making things more complicated than they are. I am developing a mobile application which uses gluons charm-glisten and attach libraries and during development I run that on my Mac right from the IDE. If I want to, I can later produce executables via Gluons client-maven-plugin for my Mac or Windows and Linux as well as packages for iOS or Android which I all can distribute. So, what else do you want to achieve?